# Inserting null when variable is empty for DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have an sp that update my table from my form.
When I try the sp is running to update and leave the datetime field empty, it put the default datetime as "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000" 
How can I set it to be null?

I have checked the values my form send the filldate is empty.

I have example of sp here:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DBK_spDataUpdate]
    @FirstName    AS NVARCHAR(250)= NULL
    @FillDate     AS DATETIME = NULL
    @DataID       AS BIGINT
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE      dbo.DBK_tbData
SET         FirstName            = @FirstName,
            FillDate             = @FillDate
WHERE       DataID               = @DataID
```

Comment: set column as nullable in table

Comment: >>>from my form<<< This means that from your form you pass not NULL, but smth else, I think you pass an empty string ('') that is then converted to 19000101 by server

Comment: Not clear how you're calling it but the problem sounds like you're passing an *empty string* as the parameter and letting SQL Server perform an implicit conversion to a `datetime` value. Instead of passing an *empty string*, pass the `NULL` literal instead.

Comment: Empty and *`NULL`* aren't the same thing. If you pass an Empty String (`''`) to a datetime variable, it will default to `'1900-01-01'`. Are you passing an empty string, or a *`NULL`*?

Comment: @Larnu, I am passing empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a small crystal ball here, but I believe the OP is passed an empty string (`''`) to the datetime parameter, not a *`NULL`*. These are two very different values; as `''` will result in the datetime `0` (which is `1900-01-01'`).

If this guess is correct, then you could use `NULLIF`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DBK_spDataUpdate] @FirstName    AS NVARCHAR(250)= NULL,
                                         @FillDate     AS DATETIME = NULL,
                                         @DataID       AS BIGINT AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE      dbo.DBK_tbData
    SET         FirstName            = @FirstName,
                FillDate             = NULLIF(@FillDate, '19000101')
    WHERE       DataID               = @DataID;
```

Otherwise, instead of passing an empty string, pass a *`NULL`*.

Comment: @FahadAlt You're welcome. I'd consider having a rethink, however, on how you pass your data to your SQL Server. There's a very important distinction between *`NULL`* and `''`, and you need to ensure you use them correctly. As you've seen, passing `''` to some data types will generate a different value to what you expected (for example, `''` as a number is `0`, and as a date is `'1900-01-01'`). Passing `''` also means that you will not use the default value of a column or parameter. If you want to use a default value of a parameter, don't pass the parameter, and for a table, pass *`NULL`*.